# How do I solve these parse errors in Verilog?

Tags: verilog

For academic purpose I'm trying to code in Verilog a *Parallel Carry Adder* but the code won't compile because of several errors that I frankly don't understand. Here is the code:

```
 1  module full_adder(a,b,c_in,s,c);
 2    input a,b,c_in;
 3    output s,c;
 4    assign s = a ^ (b ^ c_in);
 5    assign c = (a & b) | (c_in & (a | b));
 6  endmodule

 8  module rc_adder(a,b,cin,s,cout);
 9    input a,b,cin;
 10   output s,cout;
 11   parameter N = 32; // bits
 12   wire[N-1:0] a;
 13   wire[N-1:0] b;
 14   wire[N-1:0] s;
 15   wire cin;
 16   wire cout;
 17   wire[N-1:0] _c;
 18   assign cout = _c[N-1];

 20   full_adder add0(.a(a[0]),.b(b[0]),.c_in(cin),.s(s[0]),.c(_c[0]));
 21   genvar i;
 22   generate
 23     for (i = 1; i < N; i = i + 1) begin:gen_adder
 24       full_adder addN(.a(a[i]),.b(b[i]),.c_in(_c[i-1]),.s(s[i]),.c(_c[i]));
 25     end
 26   endgenerate
 26  endmodule
```

on the lines from 21st to 25th I get thees errors:

- *(21): parse error, expecting "("*
- *(23): parse error, expecting 'error' or "(" or 'IDENTIFIER'*
- *(23): parse error, expecting 'error' or ")"*
- *(23): parse error, expecting 'error' or ")"*
- *(23): parse error, expecting 'error' or ")"*
- *(23): parse error, expecting 'error' or ";"*
- *(25): parse error*

Please help...

Comment: Is there code you're not showing us? And you don't have the line numbers literally in the code, do you?

Comment: Nope, this is all the code. As for the numbers, I've explicitly written them to make it easier to find the lines giving problems

Answer (score 0):

Best guess is your simulator only supports or defaulting to IEEE1364-1995 (aka Verilog-95). The `generate` feature was added in IEEE1364-2001 (aka Verilog-2001 or v2k).

First make sure your simulator supports Verilog-2001. Then make sure that 2001 features are enabled. Most modern simulator default to Verilog-2001 or Verilog-2005 and have flags to roll back to Verilog-95.

I was able to recreate similar error messages on [EDAplaygound](https://www.edaplayground.com/) when I forced the simulators to run in Verilog-95 mode.

---

I saw a lot of warning with your module header code with various simulators on [EDAplaygound](https://www.edaplayground.com/). Some simulators throw errors. When I changed it to bellow it was cleaner and ran properly.

```
module rc_adder(a,b,cin,s,cout);
  parameter N = 32; // bits
  input  [N-1:0] a;
  input  [N-1:0] b;
  input          cin;
  output [N-1:0] s;
  output         cout;
  wire   [N-1:0] _c;
```

Verilog-2001 and above also supports an ANSI style module header which is even simpler and cleaner. If you change your module header to ANSI style and you get more errors, then it means your simulator does not support Verilog-2001 or not enabled.

```
module rc_adder #(parameter N = 32) (
  input  [N-1:0] a, b
  input          cin,
  output [N-1:0] s,
  output         cout );
  wire   [N-1:0] _c;
```